# Is "boyfriends with" proper written english?

Tags: phrases, expressions

"I'm boyfriends with that guy over there -- the one in the grey blazer."

This sounds completely fine to me in spoken English, but just looks incorrect to me when written. Does anyone have additional information to help me suss this out?

Comment: What's it supposed to mean? That the speaker is the blazer guy's girlfriend? Asking as a native speaker...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Sounds like two guys are each other's boyfriend. You know, like saying I'm friends with that person.

Comment: @tchrist Ah, that could be. It would be more linguistically interesting if it were a non-mutual use of the term :) but that does seem more likely.

Comment: This might be a better fit over at [ell.se]. Please give more details about who is who.

Comment: Generally, you are the boyfriend or girlfriend **of** someone. However, kids probably say "with". We do say: to be friends with someone.

Comment: You can be "Xes with" many types of people with whom you have a reciprocal relationship (i..e. you are an X of them, and they are an X of you). So, for example, you can be *colleagues with, siblings with, enemies with* other people. You can be *boyfriends with* or *girlfriends with* someone if they are of the same gender as you. (Otherwise the relationship is not reciprocal, because one of you is not a boyfriend/girlfriend of the other). There is no play on the word *friend* involved, nor an extension of it.

Comment: It might look incorrect just because gay relationships haven't been the sort of thing people talked about casually until relatively recently, outside of the LGBTQ community (so you're not used to seeing it).

Answer (score 5):

As a parallel to what's going on here, look at the phrasing **to be friends with [someone]**, which has been around since the 16th century and is still current. Oxford English Dictionary, under "[friend, n. and adj](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74646)," phrase P1.b:

> b. to be (also †hold, keep, stay) friends with: to be on good or intimate terms with (someone); to have (someone) as a friend.
> [...]
>
> 1598   W. Shakespeare Henry IV, Pt. 1 iii. iii. 182   **I am good friends with my father** and may do any thing.

That is well-established phrasing that is also used in the present day. There are also other possible phrasings, albeit less common: *to be enemies with someone*, *to be partners with someone*.

What your phrase does is take the basic format and use *boyfriends* instead to signal the kind of relationship you have with *the guy over there*. One could do similarly with *girlfriends*. That may be unusual in formal contexts and thus considered "incorrect" by some audiences, but other people have written and spoken in that way:

> Gays who **are boyfriends with** each other appear to be friends; only other gays can tell that they are partners. (Costa, *[Male Bodies, Women's Souls: Personal Narratives of Thailand's Transgendered Youth](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Male_Bodies_Women_s_Souls/3JRkKCjg9bgC?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, 2013)

> My Sims 4 Will **is boyfriends with** Mike ... (Sad Whisper, Tumblr, Sep 14th, 2022, [as archived on Google](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:w9PA5ha9sJ0J:https://sadwhisperao3.tumblr.com/post/695402983740129281/i-my-sims-4-will-is-boyfriends-with-mike-but-he&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-e))

> i **am girlfriends with** elsa (@bampersandand, [Twitter](https://twitter.com/bampersandand/status/1180042354276720640), October 4th, 2019)

Since the recursion suggests a same-sex relationship (the subject and object are both *boyfriend* or both *girlfriend*), the usage is more restrictive than *partner* or *friend*, which presumes no gender on either side.

Comment: Is recursiveness more like double italic or more like recursion? :)

Comment: LOL. That's my idiolect with a side of math. It's recursion.

Comment: Hmmm. See my comment under the question! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. One issue with the question of origin is that no other formation (colleagues, siblings, brothers, enemies) is attested as early as *am friends with*. Early English Books Online has over 20 results for "am friends with" and zero for any of the other suggestions, suggesting a century of idiomatic use with *friend* alone. Doing the work to show all that rigorously would take a whole other question/answer, so I'll modify my claim here, but I wouldn't dismiss *friend* out of hand.

Comment: Maybe there's a point there. But this construction does seem to be productive in modern English.